# How can I use jQueryWTP with Eclipse 3.4?

Tags: jquery, eclipse

How can I use [jQueryWTP](http://www.langtags.com/jquerywtp/) with Eclipse 3.4?  I have patched the jar file, and verified that it contains the jQuery info, but I still get errors when I open a file with `$(...)`.  From what I've found while looking for a solution, this works in Eclipse 3.3, and others are having problems with Eclipse 3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the JavaScript IDE in that release is completely different than what jQueryWTP was intended for.